# Can I use different version of rails for different projects directory in Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

Currently `Rails 4.0.2` is installed in my `Windows` machine and I'm using it for several rails projects. But, I do want to use `Rails 3.2.8` version for another project.

So, my question: Can I specify the version `3.2.8` on a single project and retain `4.0.2` in all the rest by ensuring all dependencies for `3.2.8` are installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes !

Install the rails 3.2.8 gem.

Then, you can specify which version of rails you want to use :

```
rails _3.2.18_ new mySuperSecretProject
```

In each project, you can use `rails _xxx_ console`, but it is easier do directly use the binstubs : `bin/rails console`

Comment: You can also specify in your Gemfile which version you want to use. And it will automatically use the good version when you will be on the folder. Just put `gem 'rails', '3.2.18'` on top of the gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do it as Intrepidd stated.

Another way to do this is by including a specific gem version in your application Gemfile and then do a bundle install. This will tell the application to use that particular version of rails over your system version

Answer (score 0):

Rails can be installed as follows:

1) Specify the rails gem version in your project `Gemfile`

`gem 'rails','3.2.8'` OR `gem 'rails', '4.0.2'`

2) Try running `bundle install`. it will automatically install required rails version for you and will create a bundle unique for the project you are in.

3) For `rails 4.0.2` project: if `rails 3.2.8` is already installed, try running '`bundle update rails`' to upgrade the current rails version and it will install all of its dependencies in the corresponding bundle.

If you want to run these projects in different ruby versions, then in Linux platforms `RVM` is the best option. But, in windows RVM will not work. A good option will be the `Pik` tool. Pik is a tool to manage multiple versions of ruby on Windows.

Please refer [here](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2010/08/installing-rails-30-ruby-192-and-pik-on/) for the same. Hope it helps :)